# How can I fix the problem of python2.7 instead of pytho

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

i installed python3.10.7 a couple of days ago. I have never installed python2, but when I wanted to install pip it gave me that error that I have python2.7 Then I see the version of python in cmd and it gives me python2.7. Ihave never install that and I do not want version2.7 at all. what should I do

Comment: Then deinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

use **python3** python-script.py

instead of previous

**python** python-script.py

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your question is that you have checked the version of python using

```
python --version
```

If you are using Linux it is possible that Python was pre-installed in your system. But now if you have installed python 3.xx run the command(s) with **python3** or **python3.xx** (**python3.10** in your case) not just **python**. Or simply uninstall the old python as @jps has mentioned.

But if you don't want to take the risk of uninstalling the old version. Then just use the word **python3.xx**.

### Specify Python version

And in that case, check the version by,

```
python3.xx --version
```

It should give you the latest python3 version that you have just installed. Now use whatever command you want using python3. And if it gives you any other version as mentioned by @ShadowRanger use **python3.10**

### Uninstall old python

If you want to remove the old version of python from your system. Then if you are using windows.

- Go to the Control Panel >> Programs\Programs and Features.
- Click Uninstall a program link.
- Select the python version you want to uninstall and click uninstall.

But after that also remove it from the environment variables.

#### Remove from environment variables

- Search environment variables in the search bar with/in start menu.
- In System Properties menu's Advanced tab click Environment Variables button.
- In *System variables* find **Path** variable.
- Select it and click edit.
- Find the python version path you have just uninstalled (if it is there) remove it.

Then again check for python version

Comment: It's not necessarily the *latest*, just whichever version appears first in the OP's `PATH`, and (often) which installer ran last (replacing `python3` with the one specific to the version just installed). If you install Python 3.10 then Python 3.7 later, there's a non-trivial chance your `python3` will actually be 3.7.

Comment: Actually, you are right. Thank you for pointing this out. 
Updating the comment!!

Comment: I have both windows and linux on my laptop, but I use windows while using python. It might be for that? I want to uninstall python2. How should I do it?

Comment: Added the steps for removing python.

Comment: The problem is that when I want to uninstall python when I go to the programs and features tor path there is no python2 version. Python2 is only exists on cmd and not path or not even programs and features.

Comment: Okay, so in this case.. make sure that you have python2 as default python by `python --version`` command. Then find the python installation directory by `where python` command. Go to the directory by `cd <path>` _<path> doesn't include the last .exe file` i.e., <path> = ' C:\Users\anuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python2\'. And then delete the exe file by `del python.exe`.